# When i import war file to Jdeveloper, iam seeing all the files two times

Tags: jdeveloper

I have a war file. Iam importing this war file to my Jdeveloper to do some cutomization. When i import the WAR file (File -> new -> projects -> project from WAR file). When i import the WAR, iam seeing all the file (java classes, roperties classess ...) are appering two times.

Can some one please help me why iam facing this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might just be that the Application Navigator in JDev shows you files based on context of what they are rather their actual location.
So check if the files are actually the same file on the file system.